# Why does scrollTop scroll way past the given element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For whatever reason using `element.offset().top` or `element.position().top` as the value of `scrollTop` compels the browser to scroll well past the given element.

I've tried console-logging the `$(window).scrollTop()` and `element.offset().top`, and before anything happens the readouts are as expected:

- `$(window).scrollTop() == 0`
- `element.offset().top == 999`

However, when the animated scroll completes the readouts are not entirely as I would expect them to be:

- `$(window).scrollTop() == 999`
- `element.offset().top == 831` **(Unexpected, shouldn't it be 0?)**

So I guess to one degree or another the question becomes: **Why is the element's offset barely effected if the browser is scrolled `200vh`?**

(I am using parallax on the splash page, so could this be the culprit? Can adjusting the `transform: translate(X,Y)` of elements above during the scrolling process be effecting the offset of the given element?)

## HTML

```
    <body>
        <div id="splash"></div>
        <div id="sect1">
            <div id="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sect2"></div>
    </body>
```

## CSS

```
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #splash {
        height: 200vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: relative;
    }
    #sect1 {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: relative;
    }
    #sect2 {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: relative;
    }
    #downbtn {
        width: 50px;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

## jQuery

```
    function scroll() {
            var downbtn = $('#downbtn');
            var sect1 = $('#sect1');
            $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop' : sect1.offset().top
            });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){scroll();});
```

Comment: offset is  the distance of the current element relative to it's `offsetParent` node. I'm surprised it's changed at all as scrolling a page does not usually change an elements offset

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/ --says that it's relative to the document...? @JaromandaX

Comment: jquery has it's own rules then

Comment: try using sect1.position().top

Comment: The very first thing I said was: **"For whatever reason using element.offset().top or element.position().top as the value of scrollTop compels the browser to scroll well past the given element."** Both options over-scroll to the exact same spot. @MatTaylor